# delphi duplicate case label

Tags: delphi, duplicates, case

for some reason this case switch does not compile

```
var
    c: char;
begin
    case c of
        #32..#33, #35..pred('\'), succ('\')..#255, #256..#65535:
        ...
```

Compiler says "[DCC Error] poparser.pas(206): E2030 Duplicate case label"

I have checked it, and SizeOf(c) is 2, Low(c) is 0, High(c) is 65535, which means ranges should be OK.
Then pred('\') seems to be 91 and succ('\') seems to be 93, which is also OK.
I have also commented out other cases, and result is same.
So what's the problem here?

Here is complete procedure:

```
function String2PO (s:string):string;
// Converts a string to the syntax that is used in .po files
var
  i: integer;
  c: char;
  escnext:boolean;
begin
  Result := '';
  escnext:=False;
  for i := 1 to length(s) do begin
    c := s[i];
    case c of
      #32..#33, #35..pred('\'),succ('\')..#255, #256..#65535:
        begin
          if escnext then Result:=Result+'\';
          Result := Result + c;
          escnext:=False;
        end;
      '\':begin
            Result:=Result+'\\';
            escnext:=False;
          end;
      #13:; // Do nothing
      #10:begin
            Result := Result + '\n';
            escnext:=False;
          end;
      #34:begin
            Result := Result + '\"';
            escnext:=False;
          end;
      #0:begin
           Result := Result + '\0';
           escnext:=True;
         end;
      #9:begin
           Result:=Result+'\t';
           escnext:=False;
         end;
    else
      Result := Result + '\x' + IntToHex(ord(c),2);
      escnext:=True;
    end;
  end;
  Result := '"' + Result + '"';
end;
```

I have found out that if I change the line to

```
#32..#33, #35..pred('\'),succ('\')..#65535:
```

(removing the ..#255, #256..), then it compiles :)

Note: it's delphi 2009

Comment: I'd expect it to complain about the missing `;` ('c' declaration first). That's to say better copy/paste your real code, the case compiles fine here.

Comment: Most likely the error results from a not shown part of the code below in the other case conditions.

Comment: Here (with the addition of the `;` of course) it compiles. What version of Delphi are you using?

Comment: Please supply a complete program, and one that exhibits the fault.

Comment: What is your complete `case` statement (right up to and including its `end`) ?

Comment: I have added all information to the post.

Comment: Here (Delphi XE) it compiles just fine. So the error/bug must be version-dependent.

Comment: Ok, thanks, probably some bug in delphi.

Comment: i suspect that `succ('\')..#255` is treated Ansichar and `#256..#65535` as WideChar,, and with implicit conversion some duplicates happen

Comment: Since it works fine on my D2009 to, maybe there is some CodePage issue > http://www.micro-isv.asia/2008/12/choose-the-right-file-format-for-your-delphi-source-code/

Comment: You might get some slightly simpler opcode when you place this case into the else clause and catch the remaining lower chars directly.

Comment: If you want help here, I really think you will need others to repro the behaviour.

Comment: My only guess is maybe `pred` and `succ` might be overridden with some custom code?

Comment: @Arioch 'The  I suspect the same...try declaring your string as WideString and your char as WideChar

Comment: Perhaps Delphi 2009 considers #256 to be equal to #0

Comment: I have done some experiment in new clean project:
- `#255..#256` does not compile (E2011 Low bound exceeds high bound)
- `#254..#256` does not compile (same reason)
- `#253..#256` compiles :-)
I really don't understand this.